# #1305 - PROCEDURE does not exist in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `insert_or_update`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_or_update(
IN username VARCHAR(70),
    IN score INT,
IN titlein VARCHAR(70)

)
begin
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM two_player WHERE title=titlein and user1!=username and user2='') THEN
   UPDATE two_player  SET score12=score , user2=username WHERE title=titlein and user1!=username and user2='' limit 1;
ELSE
   INSERT INTO two_player  (user1,score11,title) values (username, score, titlein);
END if;
END$$    
DELIMITER ; 
call insert_or_update('sara',20,'math');
```

I create a procedure. But when I try to call it I get this error message:

```
#1305 - PROCEDURE u941310304_menu.insert_or_update does not exist
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Try replacing `$$` with `//`

Comment: It didn't work too.

Answer (score 2):

I tested you code and the call to procedure works.

Your default database is `u941310304_menu`, it seems you are creating the procedure in another db. You can create the procedure specifying the destination database.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `u941310304_menu`.`insert_or_update`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `u941310304_menu`.insert_or_update(
[...]
```

If the procedure is in another database you must specify the db name as prefix:

```
call `another_database`.insert_or_update('sara',20,'math');
```